# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. in subquery sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want to execute this query in my database.As you can see both tables A and B has one-many relations ,but i need the latest record in B.so i here is my query :

```
select *,(select top 1 ResultTest ,ResultState2 from B where GasReceptionId=A.Id order by Id desc) 
from A where OrganizationGasId= 4212
```

But i get this error

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rephrase this query as a basic join which uses an analytic function (e.g. row number) to identify the correct row's data from `B` to include with each record coming from the `A` table.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT a.*, b.ResultTest, b.ResultState2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Id ORDER BY a.ID DESC) rn
    FROM A a
    LEFT JOIN B b
        ON a.Id = b.GasReceptionId
    WHERE
        a.OrganizationGasId = 4212
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A subquery in the `SELECT` clause must return exactly one column (and one or zero rows). So you can either have two subqueries:

```
select 
  a.*,
  (select top 1 resulttest from b where gasreceptionid = a.id order by id desc) as test,
  (select top 1 resultstate2 from b where gasreceptionid = a.id order by id desc) as state
from a 
where a.organizationgasid = 4212;
```

Or, much better, move the subquery to the `FROM` clause. One way is `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select 
  a.*, r.resulttest, r.resultstate2
from a 
outer apply
(
  select top 1 resulttest, resultstate2
  from b 
  where gasreceptionid = a.id 
  order by id desc
) r
where a.organizationgasid = 4212;
```